# Checking boxes with selenium chromedriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm working on selecting checkboxes on a page from an Array list of strings. For example my array contains [wva-00:04:F3:12:A7:2E, wva-00:04:F3:12:A6:F7, wva-00:04:F3:12:A6:90]

I've tested the program and it is going inside the for loop and if statement, so I know it is finding the text from getPageSource. But using the xpath below it is throwing this error. no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//label[text()='wva-00:04:F3:12:A7:2E']"}. Please let me know what I am doing wrong. Also note, I cannot use id's such as "marked_439" these are generated differently for each page and will not be the same number.

[Web page Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14Owk.png)

```
    for(int i = 0; i < edcNumbers.size(); i++)

        if(driver.getPageSource().contains(edcNumbers.get(i)))
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='"+edcNumbers.get(i)+"']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
```

[javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vviZQ.png)

```html
    
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="yui-dt-body">
   
    <tr class="yui-dt-odd">
     <td id="yui-0-0" headers="yui-header-0" class="yui-dt-col-"><input type="checkbox" id="marked_439" name="439"></td>
     <td id="yui-0-1" headers="yui-header-1" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">wva-00:04:F3:12:A7:2E</td>
     <td id="yui-0-2" headers="yui-header-2" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">imiprairie</td>
     <td id="yui-0-3" headers="yui-header-3" class="yui-dt-col-NUMERIC"></td>
     <td id="yui-0-4" headers="yui-header-4" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA"></td>
     <td id="yui-0-5" headers="yui-header-5" class="yui-dt-col-NUMERIC"></td>
     <td id="yui-0-6" headers="yui-header-6" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">2018-07-25</td>
     <td id="yui-0-7" headers="yui-header-7" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">2018-06-18</td>
     <td id="yui-0-8" headers="yui-header-8" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">2018-11-01</td>
     <td id="yui-0-9" headers="yui-header-9" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA"></td>
     <td id="yui-0-10" headers="yui-header-10" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">203</td>
     <td id="yui-0-11" headers="yui-header-11" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">0004F3:12A72E</td>
     <td id="yui-0-12" headers="yui-header-12" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA"></td>
     <td id="yui-0-13" headers="yui-header-13" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA"></td>
     <td id="yui-0-14" headers="yui-header-14" class="yui-dt-col-edit">
      <a rel="modal" href="settings/edc/mod/439" title="Edit">
       <button></button>
      </a>
     </td>
     <td id="yui-0-15" headers="yui-header-15" class="yui-dt-col-recycle">
            <a rel="modal" href="settings/edc/rma/439" title="RMA">
              <button></button>
            </a>
          </td>
     
      
       <td id="yui-0-16" headers="yui-header-16" class="yui-dt-col-delete yui-dt-last">
        <a rel="modal" href="settings/edc/del/439" title="Delete Confirmation">
         <button></button>
        </a>
       </td>
      
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr class="yui-dt-even">
     <td id="yui-1-0" headers="yui-header-0" class="yui-dt-col-"><input type="checkbox" id="marked_440" name="440"></td>
     <td id="yui-1-1" headers="yui-header-1" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">wva-00:04:F3:12:A6:F7</td>
     <td id="yui-1-2" headers="yui-header-2" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">imiprairie</td>
     <td id="yui-1-3" headers="yui-header-3" class="yui-dt-col-NUMERIC"></td>
     <td id="yui-1-4" headers="yui-header-4" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA"></td>
     <td id="yui-1-5" headers="yui-header-5" class="yui-dt-col-NUMERIC"></td>
     <td id="yui-1-6" headers="yui-header-6" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">2018-07-25</td>
     <td id="yui-1-7" headers="yui-header-7" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">2018-06-18</td>
     <td id="yui-1-8" headers="yui-header-8" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">2018-11-01</td>
     <td id="yui-1-9" headers="yui-header-9" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA"></td>
     <td id="yui-1-10" headers="yui-header-10" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">203</td>
     <td id="yui-1-11" headers="yui-header-11" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">0004F3:12A6F7</td>
     <td id="yui-1-12" headers="yui-header-12" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA"></td>
     <td id="yui-1-13" headers="yui-header-13" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA"></td>
     <td id="yui-1-14" headers="yui-header-14" class="yui-dt-col-edit">
      <a rel="modal" href="settings/edc/mod/440" title="Edit">
       <button></button>
      </a>
     </td>
     <td id="yui-1-15" headers="yui-header-15" class="yui-dt-col-recycle">
            <a rel="modal" href="settings/edc/rma/440" title="RMA">
              <button></button>
            </a>
          </td>
     
      
       <td id="yui-1-16" headers="yui-header-16" class="yui-dt-col-delete yui-dt-last">
        <a rel="modal" href="settings/edc/del/440" title="Delete Confirmation">
         <button></button>
        </a>
       </td>
      
     
    </tr>
   
    <tr class="yui-dt-odd">
     <td id="yui-2-0" headers="yui-header-0" class="yui-dt-col-"><input type="checkbox" id="marked_441" name="441"></td>
     <td id="yui-2-1" headers="yui-header-1" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">wva-00:04:F3:12:A6:90</td>
     <td id="yui-2-2" headers="yui-header-2" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">imiprairie</td>
     <td id="yui-2-3" headers="yui-header-3" class="yui-dt-col-NUMERIC"></td>
     <td id="yui-2-4" headers="yui-header-4" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA"></td>
     <td id="yui-2-5" headers="yui-header-5" class="yui-dt-col-NUMERIC"></td>
     <td id="yui-2-6" headers="yui-header-6" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">2018-07-25</td>
     <td id="yui-2-7" headers="yui-header-7" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">2018-06-18</td>
     <td id="yui-2-8" headers="yui-header-8" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">2018-11-01</td>
     <td id="yui-2-9" headers="yui-header-9" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA"></td>
     <td id="yui-2-10" headers="yui-header-10" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">203</td>
     <td id="yui-2-11" headers="yui-header-11" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA">0004F3:12A690</td>
     <td id="yui-2-12" headers="yui-header-12" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA"></td>
     <td id="yui-2-13" headers="yui-header-13" class="yui-dt-col-ALPHA"></td>
     <td id="yui-2-14" headers="yui-header-14" class="yui-dt-col-edit">
      <a rel="modal" href="settings/edc/mod/441" title="Edit">
       <button></button>
      </a>
     </td>
     <td id="yui-2-15" headers="yui-header-15" class="yui-dt-col-recycle">
            <a rel="modal" href="settings/edc/rma/441" title="RMA">
              <button></button>
            </a>
          </td>
     
      
       <td id="yui-2-16" headers="yui-header-16" class="yui-dt-col-delete yui-dt-last">
        <a rel="modal" href="settings/edc/del/441" title="Delete Confirmation">
         <button></button>
        </a>
       </td>
```

Comment: You could do some editing to provide a nice MCVE example using the HTML/CSS/Javascript snippets features integrated to stack overflow.

Comment: Have you tried this. "driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[normalize-space(.)='"+edcNumbers.get(i)+"']/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']")).click();"

Comment: Can u pass td instead of label in xpath and let us know.

Comment: Could you please copy/paste the HTML or link to the website?  Images of code are not very helpful especially if you are looking to find the most efficient xPath/CSS Selector.

Comment: I've tried all of the code suggestions above and it is still showing the same error. I've added more html above to hopefully help. Both my program and the html are fairly large, so I don't want to post the entire thing. Let me know what else I can do to help clear any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the XPath try locating the element by ID:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("yui-0-1")).click();
```

I think that's the element you were trying to grab anyway.

Comment: This seems to select the entire row, but not the checkbox. Also, all row header id's change. If you see above, one row will have yui-0-0 then the next row has yui-1-0. I need to select specific checkboxes that will vary in rows according to the device ID i'm looking for on the page.

Comment: So it sounds like you want to search by the inner HTML of the element.  That can be accomplished with `driver.findElement(By.xpath("[text()[contains(., 'wva-00:04:F3:12:A7:2E'")]])`

Comment: Yes, I want to check the box next to the text found. But I tried the code below and it gave me an error saying it's not a valid xpath expression: driver.findElement(By.xpath("[text()[contains(., '"+edcNumbers.get(i)+"')]/preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help guys, you all contributed to finding the solution. I was able to solve this with a different approach by finding the text in the array and then grabbing its ID and adding it to a different list. Since the checkbox IDs are only different by one number (i.e. yui-0-1 to yui-0-0) I just changed the string to match the checkbox ID in order to select it.

```
wvaIDs.add( driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '"+edcNumbers.get(i)+"')]")).getAttribute("id"));

char numToChange = wvaIDs.get(i).charAt(wvaIDs.get(i).length()-1);
int a=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numToChange));  
a--; 
String newName = wvaIDs.get(i).substring(0,6)+a;
driver.findElement(By.id(newName)).click();
```